# Does this ceiling look like it contains asbestos?

Tags: ceiling, leak, asbestos

I noticed water dripping from my kitchen ceiling. I informed my parents about it and they decided the best thing to do was rip part of the ceiling off? I am very worried about this as I think it may contain asbestos like one of those popcorn ceilings. Thanks for reading.

[image]

Comment: When was the house built and in what country?

Comment: you're going to have to wait until imgur catches up with firefox LTS or embed the picture

Answer (score 2):

That just looks like standard “mud”.  The common ceiling texture that is known to contain asbestos is “popcorn texture” not what you have.

I doubt it contains asbestos but the date the work was done and the location would also help.

if the home was built after 1984 in the US I would not worry about it but testing is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: Oh ok, the house is in the UK and was built in Victorian times so I think early 1900s. I doubt it's the original ceiling though. Can I still make food and drink in there if just a mud ceiling, or would there still be dust from the plaster?

Comment: I thought the surface looked like sheet rock or gypsum wall board and that is  a newer surface I want to say prior to the late 40’s everything was lath and plaster. But folks closed out your photos not paying attention to the examples were not what you had. A little sheetrock dust is not hazardous I probably have consumed many kilograms of It in my life time.

Comment: @EdBeal  I voted it as duplicate because that answer said "You have to send it to a lab to know for sure".  That applies to this question too.  You even closed out by stating "testing is the only way to know for sure'.  Stating we're not "paying attention" is a little rough..... but I do like your answer. +1

Comment: Well after 50 years of building and 25 of regular testing I have never had a mud only come back positive, so join in with those that don’t or have not tested anything , just saying absolutely different than the photos with long fibers, in the case of the examples “horse hair” when it is fiber that is white almost 100% asbestos black fibers not so much.